# How do I change kivy screen content when a condition is met?

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I want to be able to change the content on the next kivy screen if based on what is selected on the previous screen. For an over-simplified example, lets say there is a switch on screen 1. If that switch is active, there is a button on screen 2. If it is in-active, there is not a button on screen 2. How would I go about making this work?

Answer (score 0):

What I personally do is saving the ids of the different layouts like this:

There are 2 screens in this example, screen2 containing a gridlayout that you want to access from the first screen (to change the button). You just save the ids in a global variable so you can acces it from other screens.

```
ids_gridXYZ = ''


class gridXYZ(GridLayout): # this gridlayout contains a button with id: "button_id"
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(gridXYZ, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        global ids_gridXYZ
        ids_gridXYZ  = self.ids


class screen2(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(screen1, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.add_widget(gridXYZ())

   


class screen1(Screen):
    
    def switch_pressed(self, instance, value): #these 3 parameters are important -> dont forget instance or it won't work
        if value is True: #on
            global ids_gridXYZ
            ids_gridXYZ["button_id"].text = "switch_on"


        else: #off
            global ids_gridXYZ
            ids_gridXYZ["button_id"].text = "switch_off"
            


    


And in the kivy file something like this:
<Screen1>:
    Switch:
          id: xyz
          active: False
          on_active: root.switch_pressed()
```